# Spring Data MongoDB not able to load reference collection (@DBRef)

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have two collections in a mongo database named **failurecauses** and **statistics**.
Each statistics has a reference to the list of failure causes.

I have another Spring boot application with **spring-boot-starter-data-MongoDB** where I am trying to load the statistics.

Here I can find the statistics element but the references failure causes are not loading.

Could someone please help me  .

***Stastics collection entry***

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de64e537c31473444743985"),
    "projectName" : "Test",
    "buildNumber" : 5,
    "displayName" : "#5",
    "result" : "FAILURE",
    "failureCauses" : [ 
        {
            "failureCause" : {
                "$ref" : "failureCauses",
                "$id" : ObjectId("5ddcf6f98f705f000623ec39"),
                "$db" : "bfa_test"
            },
            "indications" : [ 
                {,
                    "matchingFile" : "log",
                    "matchingString" : "ERROR:"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

***FailureCauses collection entry***

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c99cfcfffb7870007bb351b"),
    "name" : " failed",
    "description" : "check build log.",
    "comment" : "",
    "indications" : [ 
        {
            "@class" : "com.sonyericsson.jenkins.plugins.bfa.model.indication.BuildLogIndication",
            "pattern" : "Execution  failed\\."
        }
    ],
    "modifications" : [ 
        {
            "user" : "abcv",
            "time" : ISODate("2019-03-26T07:07:59.872Z")
        }
    ],
    "lastOccurred" : ISODate("2019-09-16T05:38:45.623Z")
}
```

***Spring StaticsRepository***

```
public interface StatisticsRepository extends MongoRepository<Statistic, String> {

    Collection<Statistic> findByProjectNameAndBuildNumber(String projectName,
            Integer buildNumber);
}



@Document(value = "statistics")
public class Statistic implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String projectName;
    private String buildNumber;
    private String master;
    private Long duration;
    private String result;
    @DBRef
    private List<FailureCause> failureCauses;
}


@Document(value = "failureCauses")
public class FailureCause implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String comment;
    private Date lastOccurred;
    private List<String> categories;
    private List<Indication> indications;
    private List<FailureCauseModification> modifications;
}
```

***Output from Querying statistics***

```
[
    {
        "id": "5de64e537c31473444743985",
        "projectName": "Test",
        "buildNumber": "5",
        "master": null,
        "duration": 490,
        "result": "FAILURE",
        "failureCauses": [
             {
                "id": null,
                "name": null,
                "description": null,
                "comment": null,
                "lastOccurred": null,
                "categories": null,
                "indications": [
                    {
                        "pattern": ".*some error.*",
                        "matchingString": "some error"
                    }
                ],
                "modifications": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you running the query `@Query("{'failureCauses' : {'projectName' : ?0 , 'buildNumber' : ?1 }}")`  in `Statistic` collection and that means `Statistic` should have field like `failureCauses.projectName` and `failureCauses.buildNumber`, but as per your post, no such field inside `failureCauses`. `buildNumber` and `projectName` are in Statistic collection but not inside another object.  Proivde another collection details.

Comment: I am trying to load the statistics collections and expecting the referenced failurecauses to be load along with the statistics .

Comment: But `findByProjectNameAndBuildNumber` will not work because of the wrong `@Query` annotation.

Comment: i will modify the @Query or function name if require . Can you please tell what modification require ?

Comment: please answers, it might help you if the above-posted collection records are correct.

Comment: Does the below answer solved your problem?

Comment: No . Problem is still happening .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restructuring of the Model classes solved the problem ,

Below is the correct model which mapped the mongo db statistics collection schema

***FailureCause Model***

```
@Document(value = "failureCauses")
public class FailureCause implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @param id            the id.
     * @param name          the name of this FailureCause.
     * @param description   the description of this FailureCause.
     * @param comment       the comment of this FailureCause.
     * @param lastOccurred  the time at which this FailureCause last occurred.
     * @param categories    the categories of this FailureCause.
     * @param indications   the list of indications
     * @param modifications the modification history of this FailureCause.
     */
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String comment;
    private Date lastOccurred;
    private List<String> categories;
    private List<Indication> indications;
    private List<FailureCauseModification> modifications;
}
```

***Statistic Model***

```
@Document(value = "statistics")
public class Statistic implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String projectName;
    private String buildNumber;
    private String master;
    private Long duration;
    private String result;
    private List<FailureCauses> failureCauses;
}
```

***FailureCauses Model***

```
public class FailureCauses implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @DBRef
    FailureCause failureCause;

    /**
     * @return the failureCause
     */
    public FailureCause getFailureCause()
    {
        return failureCause;
    }

    /**
     * @param failureCause the failureCause to set
     */
    public void setFailureCause(FailureCause failureCause)
    {
        this.failureCause = failureCause;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the Collections `statistic` records the `@Query` parameters should be modified as below:

```
public interface StatisticsRepository extends MongoRepository<Statistic, String> {

@Query("{'projectName' : ?0 , 'buildNumber' : ?1 }")
Collection<Statistic> findByProjectNameAndBuildNumber(String projectName,
        Integer buildNumber);
}
```

Because these two fields are at the top level in the collection `statistic`. Not as fields inside the sub-document `failureCauses`.